# Parsing error in in CTE query SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have written a CTE query and I am executing the query in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio:

```
WITH DependencyHierarchy(processName, dependProcessName) AS
(
    SELECT
       processName,
       dependProcessName,
       1 as HierarchyLevel
    FROM processDependency

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        e.processName,
        e.dependProcessName,
        eh.HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel
    FROM 
        processDependency e
    INNER JOIN 
        DependencyHierarchy eh ON e.dependProcessName = eh.processName
)
SELECT *
FROM DependencyHierarchy
ORDER BY HierarchyLevel, processName, dependProcessName;
GO
```

It throws this error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 1,Token in error = WITH ]

The table has this data:

```
    processName dependProcessName
    P1          P2
    P2          P3
    P3          P4
    P4          P5
    P6          P7
```

Comment: Do you have any code above the CTE? What happens if you add a `;` before `WITH`?

Comment: it does not work even with a ; before with..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [WITH
> common_table_expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):
>
> column_name
>
> Specifies a column name in the common table expression. Duplicate names within a single CTE definition are not allowed. **The number of
> column names specified must match the number of columns in the result
> set of the CTE_query_definition.**
>
> **The list of column names is optional
> only if distinct names for all resulting columns are supplied in the
> query definition.**

Add column `HierarchyLevel` to `cte` column list:

```
WITH DependencyHierarchy(processName,dependProcessName, HierarchyLevel)
AS
(
   ...
)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/466689)**</kbd>

or just leave it empty (column names will be derived from first `SELECT`):

```
WITH DependencyHierarchy AS
(
   ...
)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/466689)**</kbd>

Comment: ..yes.. I think its the issue with the editor.. :( .. This should work in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio right?

Comment: @DeepakKumar Yup, check both demos.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and specially for that LiveDemo.. That's an awesome thing which I was not aware of.. :)