# Parsing error in Microsoft SQL Server Management studio 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the CTE query which I am trying to execute:

[Parsing error in in CTE query SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429695/parsing-error-in-in-cte-query-sql-server)

The query works fine as you could see in the Live Demo but this IDE is giving me a tough time by giving me the parsing error around the "with" keyword used in the CTE query..

Comment: Did you add `;` before `WITH`? `CTE/MERGE` require that previuous statement need to be ended with semicolon.

Comment: If this does not help please provide screenshot of your IDE and error message.

Comment: Yes I added that but still it didn't work.. Also I don't have any preceeding statements..OK I will add that tomorrow morning.. Left office already.. I hope u would be there to help.. :)

Comment: @lad2025 I found the issue and have answered my question. Thanks a lot for helping me out with this. couldn't have done without your help..

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the SQL server compact edition..

When I used to create a local db in the IDE with SQL server compact edition, it didn't support the CTE but when I connected to our actual database and then ran the CTE query, it worked.

Even its given in the below link that the compact version does not support CTE:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(SQL.100).aspx